# Can you get a pointer to a {System.Array} that is inside a System::Object^?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

Ok so I have this program that accepts files the user drags and drops onto a label box.  The program is currently able to accept files that are dropped.  I then save the files into a System::Object^.  Inside the System::Object^ is a {System.Array} that holds the path of the files dropped onto the label box.

I need to be able to access the file paths in the {System.Array} inside of the System::Object^.  I am converting another program that I wrote in Visual Basic to C++; so I'm trying to keep the code of both programs pretty close to each other.  I have looked at OLE for drag and drop a little bit and I'm thinking that I should be able to perform drag and drop the way I started in this code.  I feel OLE is too much for what I need, I just need the file paths for the files.  Any ideas on how I can get the file paths?

```cpp
private: System::Void lblDragHere_DragEnter(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DragEventArgs^  e)
{
    if (e->Data->GetDataPresent(System::Windows::Forms::DataFormats::FileDrop))
        e->Effect = System::Windows::Forms::DragDropEffects::All;
    else
        e->Effect = System::Windows::Forms::DragDropEffects::None;

    lblError->Visible = false;

    blnSaveSuccessful = false;
}

private: System::Void lblDragHere_DragDrop(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DragEventArgs^  e)
{
    bool blnContinue = false;

    // Checks if the user has not set a save location for the files.
    if (lblSaveLocation->Text == "Current Save Location")
    {
        lblError->ForeColor = Color::Red;
        lblError->Text = "Please select a save location first.";
        lblError->Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblError->Visible = false;

        // Checks to see if the user actually dropped anything onto lblDragHere
        if (e->Data->GetDataPresent(DataFormats::FileDrop))
        {
            System::Object ^ MyFiles;

            // Assign the files to the array.
            MyFiles = e->Data->GetData(DataFormats::FileDrop);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not C++ and not Visual-C++, also not Visual Basic. This is C++/CLI. Retagged accordingly

Comment: What is the motivation for porting program from VB to C++/CLI? Should your VB and C++/CLI project keep interoperability?

Comment: I am trying to change the program from visual basic to c++ because my vb program has problems with some large .TIFF images.  I opened the images that were giving me errors in c++ with no problems.

Comment: I want them as close as possible because the people debugging the program mainly deal with visual basic and they are not very familiar with c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to directly get the data as a cli array of file names with a cast:

```
if(e->Data->GetDataPresent(DataFormats::FileDrop))
{
    // Assign the files to the array.
    array<String^>^ myFiles = (array<String^>^)e->Data->GetData(DataFormats::FileDrop);

    // Do something with the files
    for each(String^ file in myFiles)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

(You should use `void` instead of System::Void, it's more readable)